# Init angular-slick-slider on pagePush

Tags: angularjs, slider, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, slick.js

```html
<ons-template id="atendimento.html">
  <ons-page id="atendimento" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <ons-toolbar>
      <section class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
          <ons-icon icon="menuic"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </section> 
      <section class="center">
        Atendimento
      </section>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <section class="showConsultores" ng-app="MyApp" >     
      <section class="slick-container">
        <slick infinite=true slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3>
          <section class="slick-item" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div><img src="{{ image.url }}" /></div>
          </section>
        </slick>
      </section>   
    </section><!-- showCOnsultores -->

  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

I have a slick slider on a ons-template, and I need it to initialize when this template/page is pushed. How can I do that?
I have a template and a div into it with a ng-app="MyApp" and a ng-controller="MyCtrl"

Here is what I've done already:

```html
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['slickCarousel'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($http, $scope, $interval) {

  $scope.images = [{
    url: 'http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7b87e6452c01724c8e917c4e08dce2f7?s=90&d=mm&r=g'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.guiadafarmacia.com.br/images/resized/images/screen_shot_2015-04-30_at_3_90_90.png'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.guiadafarmacia.com.br/images/resized/images/screen_shot_2015-04-30_at_3_90_90.png'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.guiadafarmacia.com.br/images/resized/images/screen_shot_2015-04-30_at_3_90_90.png'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.guiadafarmacia.com.br/images/resized/images/screen_shot_2015-04-30_at_3_90_90.png'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.jmensura.com.br/img/call_center.jpg'
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the module it looks like a plain `ng-if` is used to initialize the carousel:

```
<slick ng-if="numberLoaded">
    <div ng-repeat="i in number">
        <div class="" ng-include="'tpl.html'"></div>
    </div>
</slick>
```

You can set the `numberLoaded` (or some other trigger flag) on your state/route resolve function. Not sure if this helps